# Is it correct to let the viewmodel add children to its view?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

Im currently learning about the MVVM pattern in WPF. I think it is really cool but my **question is**: is it correct to use the viewmodel directly for appending children to its view?

For example lets assume we had a method which contains a loop which adds new rows to a grid when a button is clicked. Should my ViewModel only contain pure data or can it also contain logic for placing new elements on the field? As well as removing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it correct to use the viewmodel directly for appending children to its view?

No. The view model shouldn't know about any view elements.

> Should my ViewModel only contain pure data or can it also contain logic for placing new elements on the field? As well as removing them.

The former. The view model may expose a collection of data objects that the view happens to display in a `Grid`. Or some other kind of panel. The view model doesn't care about which.

You would typically use an `ItemsControl` in the view to display the items in a view model collection, i.e. the `ItemsControl` binds to the source collection and displays a visual representation of each item in a panel.

Comment: Do you have any source with an example?

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1160/wpf-itemscontrol-fundamentals-part1

Comment: I am allowed to create items programatically though right? I mean in the viewmodel and append it to the itemscontrol with DataContext = array